# How to access offsite referer (and first page visited on site) via PHP on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I'm trying to get three things into a hidden form field in a Wordpress page:

1. The last "offsite" page visited before someone visited any page on my site (e.g., quite possibly a Google page)
2. The first page they visited on my site
3. The last page on my site before they went to the form page

The third one is easy (just use ), but the first two are giving me problems.

I'm trying to save #1 and #2 by using session variables, so that on every page, in the header, I have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['offsite_referer'])) {
  $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
if (! isset($_SESSION['first_page'])) {
  $_SESSION['first_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
?>
```

Then further down I have, as test code (to be changed to input type=hidden etc. later):

```
<p>offsite_referer: <?= $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] ?></p>
<p>first_page: <?= $_SESSION['first_page'] ?></p>
```

(FWIW, I also have session_start() at the top of my wp-config.php. Yes, my site has register_globals turned off.)

For some reason, $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] *always* ends up as my home page, even when I hit the form page (/free-reports) directly via link from another site. Similarly, first_page *always* shows up as /

Yes, I'm clearing all my cookies etc. between attempts, to force a new session to be created.

This code used to work fine on my pre-Wordpress site, so I can only think it has something to do with WP, specifically perhaps WP's redirection (WP's mod_rewrite stuff in .htaccess)

I tried changing $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to wp_get_original_referer() but it seemed to have no effect.

Incidentally, if I access my form page (at /free-reports/) as the first page on my site (after clearing cookies etc.) and printing $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], it correctly shows the last offsite page - even though $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] doesn't.

I'm pretty perplexed, and have spent a fair amount of time trying to figure it out on my own, so any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note please be aware that depending how the user gets to your site if using Internet Explorer you may not actually get a referrer value: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you can't really get the referer URL since some browsers don't send that and some people disable that, but here's how you could do that and I'll give you some extra tips here:

```
//first of all, initialize the session
session_start();
//Now call logvisit() to log where the user is coming from
logvisit();
function logvisit() {
         $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
         $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //Gets the browser the user is using
         //If you want to test it (disable the code below if you don't want to print that information):
         echo "Offsite referer: $_SESSION['offsite_referer']<br>";
         echo "Browser: $browser<br>";
}
```

Then to destroy the session you can use `unset($_SESSION['offsite_referer']);`
This is how I usually do it, and it's often a tidy way to do it.

Comment: Have you tested this code with Wordpress? My code works fine with non-Wordpress sites, it seems to be Wordpress that's destroying/replacing the original HTTP_REFERER. If you tested the above with Wordpress, what file(s) did you put the above code in?

Comment: I'm using the above code with a personal project of mine and it works fine most of the time. Maybe you should create an index page, log the referer session there and then redirect to your WordPress site. I would search for values such as: HTTP_REFERER inside your WordPress files, and if you find anything that may be interfering then disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe scunliffe had the key to this, as I was using IE to do the testing.

It works fine now, which I attribute to actually closing and restarting IE (apparently just deleting cookies doesn't do it, as you'd think, even though that works fine in Firefox).

I also changed what I was doing slightly to just save the full in-site browse history in a session variable, rather than only first and last page on the site.

The code I ended up with was the following, which is just at the top of my theme's header.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['site_history'])) {
   $_SESSION['offsite_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $_SESSION['site_history'] = '';
}
$_SESSION['site_history'] .= ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ';');
?>
```

I originally had session_start() also in wp-config.php when I was trying to figure this out, but was able to remove it (leaving just the above code in header.php) and things still work fine.

In case anyone finds this page wanting to do something similar, I was able to access this info in my WP page by adding the following to my theme's functions.php:

```
function get_offsite_referer() { return $_SESSION['offsite_referer']; }
add_shortcode('offsite-referer', 'get_offsite_referer');
function get_site_history() { return $_SESSION['site_history']; }
add_shortcode('site-history', 'get_site_history');
```

and then to pass the info on my Wordpress page/form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="offsite_referer" value="[offsite-referer]" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_history" value="[site-history]" />
```

scunliffe, if you'd posted your comment as a "reply" I would have "accepted" it, since it was what most closely led me in the right direction, but as a comment I could only upvote it so that's what I did. Thanks!